# How do I use <model viewer> to upload and display a model onto my site?

Tags: javascript, html, model, viewer

I am currently working on a portfolio site through Cargo. I have minor understanding of writing script but have been attempting to load a 3D model onto my homepage. I found the  tag and was wondering how to make it work, it is not visible on the screen right now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
    
<model-viewer src="https://files.cargocollective.com/c1743864/exp_flower_oldv.obj" shadow-intensity="1" camera-controls touch-action="pan-y" generate-schema></model-viewer>
</body></html>
```

The code above I have attempted it and Cargo accepts it but the model is not visible. For

```
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js">
```

Do I copy and paste the code from this link and save it as an html file to then upload it onto cargo?